# EAR applications using Apache server

Tags: java, apache, jpa

I am trying to create an EAR application that contains (EJB,JPA an dynamic web project), when I start to annotate my classes with @Entity,@Table and other jpa annotations I get errors as what, eclipse cannot resolve these annotations.I changed the server to wildfy and it works perfectly.But i want to work with apache, is that server support working with annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Apache dont have these Libs. You can add it to the server manual (lib folder) or you ship this to the server in your EAR file.

Other option use Apache TomEE its a full server.

Comment: Thank you, I will add java persistence libs !

Answer (score 0):

If by Apache you mean Apache Tomcat then you should know that Tomcat is not full Java EE application server and cannot host EAR's on it's own. You should try using [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) which is, essentially, Tomcat extended to become full Java EE application server.